# Retrieving contact details from contact id using collection select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use the following collection select to let users pick the contact name.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :contact %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:contact, current_user.contacts.all, :id, :name, prompt: true, class: "form-control") %>
</div>
```

But, instead of name, it's the id that's displayed when I use `email.contact` in the show page. I have tried using email.contact.name and it returns a NoMethodError. As for the associations, Email has_many contacts and contacts belongs_to email. I even tried using inverse_of these association, but still unable to retrieve the contact name. Is there a workaround that could solve this?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `But, instead of name, it's the id that's displayed when I use email.contact in the show page`? What does it have to do with collection_select? Email has many contacts so it should be email.contacts and it'll give you a collection of records not a single record

Comment: @mandeep the drop down shows the names of all contacts. But, it's the id that gets saved when the submit button is hit. For example, if John is selected, John's user id is saved instead of the name. In the collection_select that I'm using it looks like it's the id gets saved by default. Not sure, how to display the name of the contact from the stored user id in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [`collection_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select)

```
collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

If you look at docs it says

> The :value_method and :text_method parameters are methods to be called on each member of collection. The return values are used as the value attribute and contents of each  tag, respectively.

***So you need to pass value_method as the method you want it to save in db, right now you are using it as id.*** To save name you can do something like this:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:contact, current_user.contacts.all, :name, :name, prompt: true, class: "form-control") %>
```

Comment: I tried this already. The problem is, I need the contact_id for the background mailer to send emails. So, I'll have to display the name in the show page but use the contact id in the db for the workers. That's why mentioned the associations earlier. Wondering how to use that if possible.

Comment: @user3224820 sorry but didn't get you. In your earlier comment you mentioned that you want to save name in db and not you are saying that you want id? Why don't you save id of contact in db? If your associations are correctly setup then you can always get other information from the id

Comment: sorry for the confusion. The associations are set up correctly. So, ideally I should be able to use <%= email.contact.name %> since the id is stored in db, right? Instead I get a  NoMethodError - undefined method `name' for "2":String. 2 is the contact id in this case.

Comment: @user3224820 I think I got your problem. When you have contact belongs to an email rails look for an attribute called contact_id in emails table so you need to first change your contact field to contact_id so it can find your correct contact. You need to store contact id in this field. Also since email has many contacts to you'll have to use email.contacts, it'll give you a active record relation or in simple terms a collection of records. For details checkout http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association

Comment: You're correct. There has to be a foreign key association in form of contact_id and not just contact to make this work seamlessly. Thanks for the help!